# Change column type when writing dataframe to excel

Tags: python, pandas

I am writing multiple `dfs` to an excel and I am trying to change certain index types to percentage, pound and others.

One of the `df` look like this ( dummy df ) :

```
            2019            2020            2021        2022
A           40              40              51          58
B           5               40              54          97
C           0.3             0.5             0.5         0.8
D           2000            40              200         300
E           0.02            1               0.25        0.19
```

So I would like to change the index `E` to be type `percentage` when writing to excel, same thing would happen if I would select the whole row in excel and click `%` button to change the type.

I tried:

```
with pd.ExcelWriter(f'{name}.xlsx',  engine="openpyxl", mode="a") as writer: 

    for cat in cats: # creating multiple dfs
        df_temp = df_main[df_main['Category'] == cat]
        df_temp.to_excel(writer, sheet_name = cat)

        # Get the xlsxwriter workbook and worksheet objects.
        workbook  = writer.book
        worksheet = writer.sheets[cat]

        # Add some cell formats.
        format1 = workbook.add_format({'num_format': '#,##0.00'})
        format2 = workbook.add_format({'num_format': '0%'})

        worksheet.set_row('10', 18, format2)
```

The result I am looking for is :

```
           2019            2020            2021        2022
A           40              40              51          58
B           5               40              54          97
C           0.3             0.5             0.5         0.8
D           2000            40              200         300
E           2%              100%            25%         19%
```

But I get an error:

> AttributeError: 'Workbook' object has no attribute 'add_format'

I don't how I should continue with this problem and if there is an easier way to change the format types when writing `dfs` to excel. I am following [this guide](https://xlsxwriter.readthedocs.io/example_pandas_column_formats.html). And is there a way to give a name of an index which row type needs changing rather than noting the row number?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have your ExcelWriter engine set to
openpyxl. The tutorial you're following calls for xlsxwriter.

`writer = pd.ExcelWriter("pandas_column_formats.xlsx", engine='xlsxwriter')`

Comment: My bad, thanks for spotting it.

Answer (score 0):

You are using `openpyxl` engine, instead of `xlsxwriter` (which is used in guide you linked).